# PhoneGap download PDF using link which is loaded via iframe

Tags: pdf, iframe, phonegap

**Here is the scenario:**

I build an android app using **PhoneGap** which is basically showing a website in an `iframe` (**NOT** using *inAppBrowser*). There are several PDF download link in that website & those work fine in browser. For some reason, download button trigger nothing if I click from app (app's `iframe`).

**This is what I've tried so far:**

*>> Force download in **.htaccess** in my website:*

```
<FilesMatch "\.(?i:pdf)$">
  ForceType application/octet-stream
  Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</FilesMatch>
```

*>> **HTML5** `download` attribute in anchor:*

```
<a href="link-to-file/file.pdf" download="file.pdf">Download</a>
```

*>> Force download using **PHP** `readfile()`*

```
$path = "/dir/to/file/filename.pdf";
$filename = "filename.pdf";
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');  
header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', filemtime($path)) . ' GMT');
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');  
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($path));  
header('Content-Encoding: none');
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');  
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $filename); 
readfile($path);
```

Nothing worked so far. Is it because the download link is coming using `iframe` in the app? How to make this work?

Thanks!

Comment: Why php? Phonegap can not read php..

Comment: php code in website which is loaded using `iframe` in phonegap app.